# What is the outer solar shade called?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, image-identification

Does this shade have a particular name? Or is it just called a **solar shade** ? [image: shade]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known as an *awning*:

> **awning** noun [ C ]
>   ​
>   a cloth or plastic cover fastened to a building or structure and supported by a frame that is used to protect someone or something from the sun or rain:
>
> The gaily striped awnings of the market stalls made an attractive scene.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awning)

Comment: I think awning is fine in the US as well. In my opinion, a "sunshade" is [something I put in my car's windshield](http://b.cdnbrm.com/images/products/large/travel_accessories/intro-tech_ultimate_reflector_car_sun_shade.jpg) to keep the car from getting too hot when it's parked.

Comment: If a word is used (almost) exclusively in the US, the Cambridge Dictionary simply writes "US _word_" behind the UK variant; here it was "US _also_ sunshade". I've seen this distinction many times inside this dictionary.